# Compound Probability of 2 Independent Events

Tags: probability

I have tried finding this out on many sites and such but they just say 
 P(A and B) = P(A) * P(B) .
My question is why do we multiply P(A) and P(B) instead of say adding them.

I apologize if this is a pretty stupid Question but I can't just seem to wrap my mind around this.

Comment: Adding P(A) and P(B), getting a result **larger** than P(A) and P(B), would be odd to evaluate the probability of the set (A and B), which is **smaller** than A and B.

Answer (score 0):

$P(A \text{ and } B) = P(A) P(B)$ is the **definition** of independence of events $A$ and $B$.  Why do we use that definition?  Because it's equivalent (if $P(B) \ne 0$) to the conditional probability $P(A|B) = P(A)$, i.e. informally it says
the probability of $A$ happening is not influenced by whether or not $B$ happens.

Answer (score 0):

If events $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, i.e. have no elements in commen (with postive probability) then $P(\text{A and B})=P(A)+P(B)$. This could be the case if we want to compute the probability of rolling a 5 or a 6 on a dice $P(\text{roll 5 or 6})=P(\text{roll 5})+P(\text{roll 6})=1/6+1/6=2/6=1/3$.
Independence is something entirely different, namely, if occurence of one event do not effect the other. This could be if you roll a dice and then roll another dice, then one could realistically assume the first roll does not effect the second one. This implies by your formula that $P(\text{roll 6 and then roll 6})=P(\text{roll 6})\cdot P(\text{roll 6})=1/6\cdot 1/6=1/36$ which is (hopefully) also what you would have guessed it to be if you had for example just counted number of potential outcomes of two tosses of a dice.

Note though that the events can be independent in a more sneaky manner than the obvious one above, so one should in general try to calculate each side of your equality to be sure.